# How to divide a numerique curve

Tags: algorithm, curve-fitting, curve

i have a table of values that constitute a curve , and i want an algorithm to use in (Java or C )that give me the values of each interval

[image]

the result thant i need =>
**Groupe 1 => (0,0)(1,1)(2,2)

Groupe 2 => (2,2)(3,2)(4,2)

Groupe 3 => (4,2)(5,1.25)(6,0.5)

Groupe 4 => (6,0.5)(7,0.5)(8,0.5)(9,0.5)

Groupe 4 => (9,0.5)(10,1.5)(11,1.5)(12,1.5)**

what are the methods that can give me the result that i showed you ?

and i need that the algorithm work also this structure not just concatenated line segments 
[image]

Comment: Is this a curve or concatenated line segments?

Comment: yes but just as an exemple but i want that the algorithm work also with all kind of curve and to transform them to linear curve .

Comment: @MarkusKull look at my edit

Comment: I guess what you are looking for is an algorithm to find local maximums/minimums, right? That seems to do the job, and there is a lot of options around, google it.

Comment: @mikus i need exactly the points of reflexion to get the groups of points that i need.

Comment: depends on the needs, you can also write something simple, like start with one point, go along the values, the first time the value changes above some threshold value you mark a segment, move your starting point and start again. After all you can remove the segments that are too short. Or already not mark them, just move the starting point, until a long one would be created. Shouldnt be hard to implement

Comment: it might be possible to calculate it using discretevalues only as well, without interpolation, you;'d need to decide to make a segment in between of points with greatly different values.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What are "the values of each interval" ? And about "the result that i showed you": you didn't show anything but the data points. The two plots you are showing are unrelated. Anyway, the curve doesn't pass through the corners. Is that what you want ?

Answer (score 1):

What you need is an interpolation algorithm. There are many with different properties and it's hard to say which one is right for you.

Basically all of them take the points you have and are able to suggest reasonable values in between.

The simplest one is linear interpolation. Given a point x,y between x1,y1 and x2,y2 you have `y = (x-x1)/(x2-x1) * y1 + (x2-x)/(x2-x1) * y2` so if you pick an x you can figure out the y. This will give you straight line segments.

If this is too simple for your application look at some curve functions. Bezier is prefered in many situation because it's fast and the curve depends on a limited number of neighboring points. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve).

That said, remember that all these are approximations, and have lots of assumptions so it's unlikely there will be one to perfectly match the ground truth.

Comment: i think he needs more than that, but that's a good start, although it might be possible with only the discretevalues too